# How do I correctly add cache information for breadcrumb parts?

Tags: 8, caching, breadcrumbs

Visiting a node *Foobar* a breadcrumb gets created which adds the parent menu structure like so:

```
$currentPluginId = $menu_link->getPluginId();
$trailIds = $this->menuActiveTrail->getActiveTrailIds('main');

foreach (array_reverse($trailIds) as $key => $value) {
  if ($value && $value !== $currentPluginId) {
    // @todo add cache per item
    $instance = $menu_link_manager->createInstance($value);
    $breadcrumb->addLink(
      new Link(
        $instance->getTitle(),
        $instance->getUrlObject()
      )
    );
  }
}

$breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(['route.menu_active_trails:main']);
```

So the breadcrumb looks like:

> Home > John Doe > **Foobar**

But if the node/ menu item of *John Doe* changes, the breadcrumb for *Foobar* stays the same.

```
dpm($instance->getUrlObject()->getRouteName());
dpm($instance->getUrlObject()->getRouteParameters());
```

gives me:

> entity.node.canonical

and

> array(
>       [node] => 25 )

How can I use that for adding each breadcrumb part as cache context/ tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with the following:

```
foreach (array_reverse($trailIds) as $key => $value) {
  if ($value && $value !== $currentPluginId) {
    // @todo add cache per item
    $instance = $menu_link_manager->createInstance($value);
    $breadcrumb->addLink(
      new Link(
        $instance->getTitle(),
        $instance->getUrlObject()
      )
    );
    $routeParams = $instance->getUrlObject()->getRouteParameters();
    if (is_array($routeParams) && count($routeParams) && isset($routeParams['node'])) {
      $breadcrumb->addCacheTags(['node:' . $routeParams['node']]);
    }
  }
}
```

As it turns out, changing a menu item without really changing the node though does not invalidate the cache so the breadcrumb would still have old menu titles. This line somehow has no impact, either

```
$breadcrumb->addCacheContexts(['route.menu_active_trails:main']);
```

So I added this to the breadcrumb:

```
$breadcrumb->addCacheTags(['config:system.menu.main']);
```

And voila. As soon as the menu title of John Doe changes, the breadcrumb on page Foobar also updates.

Maybe it's even a better idea to not add the node cache tags but only the menu cache tag. Guess you have to play with how the site behaves over time.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `\Drupal\book\BookBreadcrumbBuilder::build()` for an example. You'll want to add the cacheability metadata (or at minimum the cache tags) of the node/menu item *John Doe*.

So:

```
$breadcrumb->addCacheableDependency($entity);
```

---

You could have easily figured this out yourself: you're building a `\Drupal\Core\Breadcrumb\Breadcrumb` object… which implements `RefinableCacheableDependencyInterface`, and that interface lists all things related to cacheability.

I highly recommend you read https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache and all documentation it points to.

Comment: I've read the API and looked through the breadcrumb functions and inherited class methods. I dont have the `$node` or `$entity` object, only the nid. So I added `$breadcrumb->addCacheTags(['node:' . $instance->getUrlObject()->getRouteParameters()['node']]);`

Comment: You can load the node object. The breadcrumb will be cached on subsequent requests anyway, so you only incur the cost of loading the node once :)